# Prefixing invalid variable definition with `struct` causes C++ template to compile

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

```
class Base {
  int i;
};

template <auto V>
struct Foo {
  int a;
};


int main()
{
    struct Foo<&Base::i> struct_foo;
    Foo<&Base::i> foo;
}
```

The fist line in `main()` compiles in gcc 12.2, but the second line doesn't compile. What is the reason?

https://godbolt.org/z/eTG7cW35q

Comment: Fyi, *neither* compile with clang 14, for the same reason (`i` is private to `Base`).

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Looks like gcc bug as both should fail to compile.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because as @JasonLiam mentioned both should fail. I didn't notice the note that you mentioned one line compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108275) as both statements should fail compilation(which they do with clang and msvc).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qWTo345Po)